# How to get list of Windows's shared folders on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, samba

We have a small LAN in my office, I use Ubuntu and other PCs have Windows XP and 7 - they have some shared folder on them.

How dp I get a list of Windows's shared folders on Ubuntu in Terminal (using the command line)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `smbclient`, an "ftp-like client to access SMB/CIFS resources on servers":

```
smbclient -L hostname -U username
```

This will list all available shares to that user on the specified machine. More about smbclient is available in the manpage, just call `man smbclient`.

Answer (score 1):

And on a Mac with the [smbutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/smbutil.1.html):

```
smbutil view [-options] //[domain;][user[:password]@]server
```

and as @slhck mentioned above use the `man smbutil` for more information for MacOSX's BSD flavored command line.

Comment: the semicolon, ";", must be escaped on the command line `\;` so it is not interpreted as the end-of-command character [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233934/semicolon-on-command-line-in-linux)

Comment: The question is about Windows and Ubuntu. . . How is a command on Mac useful in this situation?

Comment: @zeel As a Mac user I got redirected here when searching relevant terms, and this has helped me